# Is it possible to use socket.io between NodeJS and AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, node.js, sockets

I have two independent applications (frontEnd and BackEnd). The backEnd is in NodeJS using express framework and the FrontEnd is in AngularJS. Is it possible to use socket.io to send a message from the server (NodeJS) to the client (AngularJS)? How I can do that? I've tried with the following code but it is not working:

server code

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
       //This message is not  showing 
      console.log("socket");
      socket.volatile.emit('notification', {message: 'push message'});
});
```

client code

```
angular.module('pysFormWebApp')
  .factory('mySocket', function (socketFactory) {
      var mySocket = socketFactory({
            prefix: 'foo~',
            ioSocket: io.connect('http://localhost:3000/')            
      });
      mySocket.forward('error');
      return mySocket;
  });

angular.module('formModule')
  .controller('typingCtrl', ['$scope', 'mySocket', typingCtrl]);
    function typingCtrl ($scope, mySocket) {

    mySocket.forward('someEvent', $scope);
    $scope.$on('socket:someEvent', function (ev, data) {
      $scope.theData = data;
      console.log(data);
    });
```

thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I set my connection up. I'm not sure if it's the best way, but it definitely works and I haven't had any performance issues to date.

**Client Code:**

```
angular.module('whatever').factory('socket', function ($rootScope) {
    var socket = io.connect('yourhost');
    return {
        on: function (eventName, callback) {
            socket.on(eventName, function () {
                var args = arguments;
                $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                    callback.apply(socket, args);
                });
            });
        },
        emit: function (eventName, data, callback) {
            socket.emit(eventName, data, function () {
                var args = arguments;
                $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                    if (callback) {
                        callback.apply(socket, args);
                    }
                });
            })
        }
    };
});

angular.module('whatever').controller("MainCtrl", MainCtrl);
function MainCtrl($scope, socket) {
    socket.on('channelname', function(data) {
            console.log("message: " + data.message);
    });
}
```

**Server Code:**

```
var Express = require('express');
var app = new Express();
var server = Http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.emit("channelname", {
    message: "messagecontent"
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks it work, the only change that can you add is in case  use express 4; change  `var Express = require('express');` for `var Express = require('express.io');`